# Test for lagged time series analysis

Tags: time-series, arima, lags

I have two time series and there is good reason to believe that one of the has a lagged effect on another one. i.e they move inversely.

What are some time series tests I could perform to

1. Validate that one of them is a lagging indicator
2. Calculate the number of lag periods

[image]

Comment: +1. For starters I think using the first differences would be more relevant. We want to compare stationary processes.

Comment: Compute and plot the cross-correlation function (maybe after lagging), can you show it?